# Jquery validate class "error" on added label (JSP)

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery-validate

I have a little problem with Jquery Validate : My form is declared in a JSP and I use "Jquery Validate" to validate fields in the form. 
Here we have the first and second input (first name, second name) :

```
            <div class="medium-6 columns">
            <input type="text"     
                   class="input_text" 
                   id="nom"          
                   name="nom"          
                   title="<fmt:message key="main_new_acc_form_p_nom" />"    
                   placeholder="<fmt:message key="main_new_acc_form_p_nom" />"
                   data-required-nom="<fmt:message key="main_new_acc_form_e_nom" />"
                   data-minlength-nom="<fmt:message key="main_new_acc_form_p_min_n" />" 
            />
            </div>
            <div class="medium-6 columns">
            <input type="text"     
                   class="input_text" 
                   id="prenom"       
                   name="prenom"       
                   title="<fmt:message key="main_new_acc_form_p_prenom" />" 
                   placeholder="<fmt:message key="main_new_acc_form_p_prenom" />"
                   data-required-prenom="<fmt:message key="main_new_acc_form_e_prenom" />"
            />
            </div>
```

Jquery Validate code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var MessageRequired_Nom              = $('input').attr('data-required-nom');
    var MessageMinlength_Nom             = $('input').attr('data-minlength-nom');
    var MessageRequired_Prenom           = $('input').attr('data-required-prenom');
    var MessageRequired_Email            = $('input').attr('data-required-email');
    var MessageValidate_Email            = $('input').attr('data-validate-email');
    var MessageRequired_Email_c          = $('input').attr('data-required-email_c');
    var MessageEqualTo_Email_c           = $('input').attr('data-equalTo-email_c');
    var MessageRequired_MotdePasse       = $('input').attr('data-required-motdepasse');
    var MessageStrongPassword_MotdePasse = $('input').attr('data-strongPassword-motdepasse');
    var MessageRequired_MotdePasse_c     = $('input').attr('data-required-motdepasse_c');
    var MessageEqualTo_MotdePasse_c      = $('input').attr('data-equalTo-motdepasse_c');

$("#form_new").validate({

    rules : {
           nom : {
                 required : true,
                minlength : 3
                 }, 
        prenom : {required:true},
         email : {
                 required : true,
                    email : true
                 },
       email_c : {
                 required : true,
                  equalTo : "#email"
                 },
    motdepasse : {
                     required : true,
               strongPassword : true
                 },
  motdepasse_c : {
                     required : true,
                      equalTo : "#motdepasse"
                 }
            },

 messages : {
           nom : {
                     required : MessageRequired_Nom,
                    minlength : MessageMinlength_Nom 
                 },
        prenom : MessageRequired_Prenom,
         email : {
                     required : MessageRequired_Email,
                        email : MessageValidate_Email 
                 },
       email_c : {
                     required : MessageRequired_Email_c,
                      equalTo : MessageEqualTo_Email_c
                 },
    motdepasse : {
                     required : MessageRequired_MotdePasse,
               strongPassword : MessageStrongPassword_MotdePasse 
                 },
  motdepasse_c : {
                     required : MessageRequired_MotdePasse_c,
                      equalTo : MessageEqualTo_MotdePasse_c  
                 }          

            }

   })
 });
```

The problem is that Jquery Validate - messages - works only for the first variable : "nom"; for all the others(prenom,email,etc) Jquery Validate creates a "label" with error class and text took from the "title" attribute of the input field and not from the declared "data-required-prenom" attribute.
See below :

```
<div class="medium-6 columns">
    <input type="text" 
           class="input_text error" 
           id="nom" name="nom" 
           title="Nom" placeholder="Nom" 
           data-required-nom="Veuillez remplir le champ Nom" 
           data-minlength-nom="Le Nom doit contenir au moins 3 caractères" 
           aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
           <label id="nom-error" class="error" for="nom">Veuillez remplir le champ Nom</label>
</div>
```

The first one is corect label = data-required-nom.

But for the second input :

```
<div class="medium-6 columns">
    <input type="text" 
    class="input_text error" 
    id="prenom" name="prenom" 
    title="Prénom" 
    placeholder="Prénom" 
    data-required-prenom="Veuillez remplir le champ Prénom" 
    aria-required="true">
    <label id="prenom-error" class="error" for="prenom">Prénom</label>
</div>
```

label = title here

Any idea?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't saw "required" for "prenom" but it still don't works. If I put for prenom:{required:MessageRequired_Nom} it works but is the wrong message (for Nom - name in french)

Comment: It's very verbose.  See my answer for how to make it concise.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying which input you want to retrieve the data attribute from.

So instead of:

```
$('input').attr('data-required-prenom');
```

Use:

```
$('#prenom').attr('data-required-prenom');
```

Comment: Marvelous Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$('input')` is too general and returns an object containing ALL `input` elements on the form.  Then when you use the `.attr()` method, it will only get attached to the first matching object.

You'll need to be more specific with your jQuery selectors...

```
var MessageRequired_Nom      = $('#nom').attr('data-required-nom'),
    MessageMinlength_Nom     = $('#nom').attr('data-minlength-nom'),
    MessageRequired_Prenom   = $('#prenom').attr('data-required-prenom'), .......
```

---

You could also use [the `.data()` method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead, and save some bytes...

```
var MessageRequired_Nom      = $('#nom').data('required-nom'),
    MessageMinlength_Nom     = $('#nom').data('minlength-nom'),
    MessageRequired_Prenom   = $('#prenom').data('required-prenom'), .......
```

---

You also don't need to define all those variables.  Use everything directly within the `messages` object...

```
....
     messages: {
        first: {
            required: function() {
                return $('[name="first"]').data('required-first');
            },
            minlength: function() {
                return $('[name="first"]').data('minlength-first');
            }
        },
        last: {
            required: function() {
                return $('[name="last"]').data('required-last');
            }
        }
    },
....
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/7j9j23kz/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/7j9j23kz/3/)**

Comment: Thank you very much